# How to set start time with datetime-type input value in JS?

Tags: javascript, datetime, input, datetime-parsing

I have a countup app. Here is the thing:
[https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-mjepwa?file=main.js]](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-mjepwa?file=main.js%5D)

I have this code in my function. It sets from when the timer starts counting.
`past = Date.parse('2023-02-8 02:20:00');`
I want to set the timer with "type="datetime-local" input.

I have no idea how to do it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can change your `Date.parse(<date>)` to use whatever the value of the input is. For example: `var elem = document.querySelector("input.time-input"); var tm = elem.value; if(!tm) { tm = new Date(); tm = tm.toISOString(); }` Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: @FiddlingAway—see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C625.0350) If the `!tm` test fails, then *tm* is a string and `tm.toISOString()` will throw an error. Hence answers should be as answers, not in comments.

Comment: Questions should include minimal code to demonstrate the issue, not reference code posted elsewhere.

Comment: @RobG Are you sure it will throw an error? Unless I'm misunderstanding you, this `var tm = ""; if(!tm) { tm = new Date(); tm = tm.toISOString(); console.log(tm); }` is showing what it's supposed to show: `2023-02-13T19:33:14.452Z` at the time of posting this comment.

Comment: @FiddlingAway—the OP wants to use a time input, not datetime. If a value has been set, it will be like "19:33", which will be parsed as an invalid date and *toISOString* will throw a range error (or similar).

Comment: @RobG *I want to set the timer with "type="datetime-local" input.* - This is in the OP's question. And in the stackblitz, this is the input: `<input   class="time-input"  type="datetime-local"  value="2024-02-8 02:20:00"/>`. When the value of that input is set (for example, to today), and when the time is entered manually (typing in the field), the value becomes something like `2023-02-16T11:11`. When this is processed like so: `var tm = Date.parse('2023-02-16T11:11'); tm.toISOString();` the output is `"2023-02-16T10:11:00.000Z"`. So, again, no error there.